# Split street, house number and addition from address

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm using a regular expression to split Dutch street, house number and addition from an address.
The addition should be optional.

```
preg_match('/(?P<address>[^\d]+) (?P<number>[\d]+)(?P<numberAdd>[^\d]+)/', $input, $matches)
```

This only works if the $input is for example Street 1A. But not if the input is only Street 1 (without addition).

So how can I split the address with the addition as optional? The addition may not contain numbers.

Comment: That's because `[^\d]+` means one or more. Try `(?P<numberAdd>[^\d]+)*` instead (it means zero or more).

Comment: Or just `\D*`. The character class isn't required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a try with:

```
preg_match('/(?P<address>\D+) (?P<number>\d+)(?P<numberAdd>\D*)/', $input, $matches)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a single regular expression that matches a lot. It's described in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/christiaanwesterbeek/c574beaf73adcfd74997). This code does German addresses as well.

```
var re = /^(\d*[\wäöüß\d '\-\.]+)[,\s]+(\d+)\s*([\wäöüß\d\-\/]*)$/i;

var adressen = [
  'Dorpstraat 2',
  'Dorpstr. 2',
  'Laan 1933 2',
  '18 Septemberplein 12',
  'Kerkstraat 42-f3',
  'Kerk straat 2b',
  '42nd street, 1337a',
  '1e Constantijn Huigensstraat 9b',
  'Maas-Waalweg 15',
  'De Dompelaar 1 B',
  'Kümmersbrucker Straße 2',
  'Friedrichstädter Straße 42-46',
  'Höhenstraße 5A',  
  'Saturnusstraat 60-75',
  'Saturnusstraat 60 - 75',
  '1, rue de l\'eglise'
], match;

adressen.forEach(function(adres) {
  match = adres.match(re)
  if (match) {
    match.shift(); // remove element 0 (the entire match)
    //match is now always an array with length of 3
    console.log(match.join('|'))
  } else {
    console.log('No match: '+adres)
  }
})
```

Here's the formatted output

```
Dorpstraat                   |    2 | 
Dorpstr.                     |    2 | 
Laan 1933                    |    2 | 
18 Septemberplein            |   12 | 
Kerkstraat                   |   42 | -f3 
Kerk straat                  |    2 | b 
42nd street                  | 1337 | a 
1e Constantijn Huigensstraat |    9 | b
Maas-Waalweg                 |   15 | 
De Dompelaar                 |    1 | B
Kümmersbrucker Straße        |    2 |
Friedrichstädter Straße      |   42 |-46
Höhenstraße                  |    5 | A
Saturnusstraat               |   60 | -75
Saturnusstraat 60 -          |   75 | //<-- problematic

No match: 1, rue de l'eglise
```

You are very welcome to provide regexp improvements, but don't forget to see if it still matches everything it use to match.

Comment: did you find any regexp improvements?

Comment: I created a repo on PHP for this matter, see: https://github.com/WebRTB/address-splitter. it is still w.i.p. though pull requests are more then welcome.